# Bootstrap 3 thumbnail slider

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

hi i'm trying to get this demo to load from http://www.bootply.com/87858 ... copied everything correctly (I think) but no luck. Any idea what is causing this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bootply.com - Bootstrap 3 Thumbnail Slider</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- CSS code from Bootply.com editor -->

<style type="text/css">
    .carousel-control {
padding-top:10%;
width:5%;
}
</style>
    </head>

    <!-- HTML code from Bootply.com editor -->

    <body  >

        <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <h1>Bootstrap 3 Thumbnail Slider</h1>

        <div class="well">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                </div>
                <!--/carousel-inner--> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
            </div>
            <!--/myCarousel-->
        </div>
        <!--/well-->
    </div>
</div>

        <script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- JavaScript jQuery code from Bootply.com editor  -->

<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
interval: 10000
})

$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
//alert("slid");
});


});
</script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me this example that you posted.

Comment: @paulalexandru the code I post ran locally fine just like the demo? odd, that it just shows the boxes vertical as if a supporting file was not read.

Comment: do you have any url? i can check that and tell you where is the problem.

Comment: @paulalexandru it's working http://nemx.me/demo/test.htm for some reason running it locally on my computer caused a slow 5-6 load delay and for the page not to load completely. runs fine on my server though. thank you.

Comment: Welcome. Happy that it works now for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to load bootstrap from another url.